# mPDF not generating PDF in firefox

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

I am using `mPDF` library for creating PDF using html data.it works fine in `google chrome`,but in `firefox` it displays nothing.No files downloaded and no errors in console.

Here is my code :

```
require_once( $destination_path."/mpdf/mpdf.php");
$target_path = $destination_path . '/uploads/reports/';
$htmlData='<span>Sample Html Content</span>';
try {
    $pdf= new mPDF();
    $pdf->debug = true;
    $pdf->SetFooter("MyApp" . '|{PAGENO}|' . date(DATE_RFC822));
    $pdf->WriteHTML($htmlData);
    $pdf->Output($fileOutputPath, 'F');
}catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e, "\n";
}
```

i am tried `ob_clean()` and `headers` for solve the issue,but it remains same .
Anyone knows how to solve this issue?